# Request user location with timed fallback

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I want to figure out what a client's position is.
Ideally they'd accept navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition but in the event that they won't, I'd like to make an ip lookup fallback and if that fails I'd like to just rely on timezone to roughly place the client's location.

I've made all of this, but `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't trigger an error if the user just ignored the popup. The `timeout` option seems to be how long it takes to resolve the location, not how long the request stays up for.

Is there a good way to auto-cancel the geo-tracking request pop-up after 10s and then fallback to something less accurate?

Comment: Make the initial request using a timeout and then clear it after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` for 10 seconds.

```
let watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successFunction, errorFunction, {timeout: 10000});
```

When it times out, go back to another way of determining the location.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: I looked into this actually but the documentation says it's monitoring when the location changes. Will it also just give you the current location the first time you call it?

Comment: Yes, you will get a location if they accept. If they do not, it will time out after 10s.

Comment: The pop-up doesn't seem to close by itself - in fact it's triggering the error state every 10s - while the tab has focus. I suppose using the fallback first and if the user clicks on the tracking thing then use accurate data might actually be the way to go.